# Modern objective C guidelines

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Where can we find all the guidelines of modern objective-C and what is the advantage of replacing the older version of code with modern objective C code. Apart from easy usage, is there any reduction in processing time?

Comment: No.  If anything, upgrading from objective-c 1.0 to 2.0 would produce slower, more verbose code.

Comment: The reason for updating is that Apple requires it, if you want to play in their playground.

Comment: @CodaFi what makes you think so? I dont want to start a flame war but I really dont think so AND I cant see how you could be right with such a _general_ statement.

Comment: @Daij-Djan Objective-C 2.0 style syntax necessitates both verbosity (if you look at 1.0, a lot of it was iVars and id's everywhere), and a 64 bit runtime (32 on iOS, but that's not the point).  Structures, primtives and objects got larger, and slower.  And may I say to you: generalities inspire generalities ;)

Comment: The 64 bit runtime is significantly faster than the old runtime in many areas (in particular, message sending and exception handling), as well as being much less fragile, and having better C++ interoperability.

Answer (score 2):

For more information see:

- WWDC 2012 [Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=405)
- WWDC 2012 [Migrating to Modern Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=413)
- [Clang Language Extensions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html)

For me, the evolution of object literals, subscripting, etc. are largely a matter of code legibility (syntactic sugar, as Grady puts it). Some of these new features, like strongly typed enums, also facilitate improved code completion. I don't know of any material performance improvements that the features introduced with Xcode 4.5 offer us over what we had with, for example, Xcode 4.3.

In short, while I'm an advocate of the new features, I don't see any need to rush out and refactor your old code.

Comment: Most of the things you list are compiler features, not language features.

Comment: CodaFi the line gets pretty blurry as a language feature requires a Clang feature...

Comment: @GradyPlayer typed enums have been around for a while.  If having a macro to make them easier is a language feature, then I wonder why we aren't just using it directly?  At compile time, it all looks the same anyhow.

Comment: rather than typed enums, i am thinking literal syntax and blocks... this answer doesn't mention enums, is that where you meant to comment

Comment: @GradyPlayer /*Things like typed enums...*/ And maybe if he'd mentioned literals and blocks, I wouldn't be so pedantic

Comment: Sorry I missed that when I re-read it... I need a nap

Comment: All of these features are language features, just like ARC. Clang's supported Objective-C is the defacto latest Objective-C.

Comment: Typed enums are a relatively new feature borrowed from C++11 actually. And yes, compiler features *are* language features.

Answer (score 0):

there can be advantages in processing time, things like fast enumeration are supposed to be much faster... ie

```
NSArray * array = [array withObjects:@"a",@"b",@"c",nil];

for (int i = 0 ; i<[array count]; i++)
{
     NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
}

should be slower than:

NSArray * array = @[@"a",@"b",@"c"];

for (id object in array)
{
    NSLog(@"%@",object);
}
```

depending on how far back you are talking, the introduction of `@property`'s makes memory management much more manageable.

Blocks are amazing!

exception handling is better now `@try{}` vs `NS_DURING`, etc.

literal syntax is just syntactic sugar... but it is nice if it is available.

Comment: The "`for (id object in array)`" is not part of the Modern Objective-C advances, is it? We've had that for a while. If anything, during the Modern Objective-C presentation, the demonstrated `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` rather than either of those two constructs.

Comment: it is modern, as it couldnt be done before Objective-C 2.0 and anything with blocks is cool

Comment: Agreed. But when I heard the OP say "Modern Objective-C", I assumed he was not talking about Objective-C 2.0, but rather all of those features that came with Xcode 4.4 and 4.5, which Apple included in their "Modern Objective-C" presentation and which are implemented if you do "Edit" - "Refactor" - "Convert to Modern Objective-C".